# Comments though Real-time update API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time

I'm trying to develop an analytics application for Facebook and I would like to count for example the number of comments a user has submitted to any kind of objects (posts, links, photos, etc...)

From browsing though the Facebook API I've noticed that the comments table is not indexed on the from user id field which means that we cannot query, for the comments starting from a user object (one has to first use a post or other object to get the comments).

I'm wondering if I could get a notification through the Real-time updates API when a user posts a comment. Also what exactly are the fields one could get notifications about through the real-time API (namely all the fields

Answer (score 0):

The fields that you can get from Real Times updates API are descripted in official docs[1]

[1] http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/